# Parser to extract URIs from RDF/XML web page for my Web-Crawler in Java

Tags: xml, parsing, web-crawler, rdf, linked-data

I am building a web Crawler for Linked Data. I have differentiated between HTML and RDF/XML page by following code:

```
public static int checktype(URL url) throws IOException
{
String contentType = ((HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()).getContentType();
System.out.println("Website is read"); 
int t=0;
if("text/html".equals(contentType)) {t=0;}
else if("application/rdf+xml".equals(contentType)) {t=1;}
System.out.println(contentType);
return t;
```

}

Now I want to parse a web page with RDF/XML data to extract all URIs from that page. I am able to find HTML parsers but not for Linked Data. Please help me further

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off using an existing library, for example [Apache Any23](http://any23.apache.org/), which already comes with code for automatically distinguishing between different formats *and* parsers for all the formats.

Answer (score 1):

see the [jena Library](http://jena.apache.org/). It contains a [RDF/XML parser](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html#ch-Reading%20RDF).